# Using PhantomJS in eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, phantomjs

Hi I am new to using PhantomJS and also Javascript. I am trying to use a PhantomJS functionality in my Javascript. I am trying to get a screenshot of a webpage and store it. I believe it can be done with PhantomJS and I have downloaded it. I have created a new Static Web Project and the tutorial, says I should get the PhantomJS executable, on the build path and I am not sure how to do this. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Nice choice on PhantomJS, i really like this and use a lot.

Here has a good example to render a simple screenshot:

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js

Just download the raw file (or entire repo).

easy easy:

`phantomjs rasterize.js http://www.google.com/ test.png`

Remember to have **write permission** on your local directory.

Also, you can explore a lot of example scripts:

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Examples

have a nice coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                    .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("D:\\screenshot.png"));
```

This creates a screenshot file and saves it so you can save the output.